# Access Violation Reading Location on std::set::erase

Tags: c++, access-violation, stdset

I have recently caught the following crash in my application:

```
m_players[0].erase(plr); -- CRASHES HERE

m_players[1].erase(plr);
```

`m_players` is declared as:

```
set<PlayerPointer> m_players[2];
```

Visual Studio shows that it is "0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024."

Compiler: Visual Studio 2008.

Diassembly: 000000014007AA3B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this] (crashed on)

So I'm assuming we're dying because of bad "this", since its a first access to this in that function. But since I watched locals/autos, this doesn't seem to be a bad pointer.

Would be nice to get a hint.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information than this.

Comment: Please provide more information about the crash by showing the error display in a debugger.

Comment: The declarations and the array initialization would help a lot.

Comment: As others said, there isnt enough info to know more about the error.

Maybe plr is not a valid reference. who knows...

Comment: WorldPacket data(SMSG_BATTLEGROUND_PLAYER_LEFT, 30);
 data << plr->GetGUID(); 

 plr was referenced before.. anyways, will include locals

Comment: How was plr built?? Might it be the case that it is not a valid iterator into the set?? That would be an explanation (and a rather simple one: plr cannot be a valid iterator into two different sets at once, so it might be the case that it is not valid in either.

Comment: plr is a Player* pointer

Answer (score 2):

Something is pointing to 0. As you are using Visual Studio compile your application in Debug mode. Type Ctrl+Alt+E and activate the exceptions when they are thrown. This will help you to detect places where things go wrong before an exception handler is run. You can then post the callstack, but I think you will then see&solve the problem easily yourself. I can imagine something bad in the destructor of whatever type is plr.

Answer (score 1):

When working with Visual Studio, it is always good to ensure the runtimes are the same. Have you verified that? (e.g. Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd))

Answer (score 0):

I think this has more to do with plr  than m_players being already deleted or not available. Can you show how you get plr, is it a local variable or is it being passed as an argument? You might want to create a local variable and then use it in erase function and see if it crashes. This way you can pin point what exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: Hmm yes, plr is passed as an argument, will try with a local variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

any chance the array is global and the problematic code is executed before the array is initialized (can happen if its inside a constructor of a global object etc) ?

Comment: hmm no

 btw, it crashes on (diassembly) 000000014007AA3B  mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]